# CDF of product of independent chi-square distributions

Tags: distributions, independence, cumulative-distribution-function, chi-squared-distribution

Assume that we have $i=1,\ldots,n$ independent chi-square distributed random variables,
$$
X_i \sim \chi^2(k_i).
$$

What is
$$
P\left(\prod_i X_i \leq c\right)
$$
for some $c>0$?

Note: I am hoping that someone knows this result already or knows where I can find it. How to derive it, I do know.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, as the cdf for $n=1$ is not closed-form, unless you involve a special function.

Comment: I think it is clear what is being asked. Moreover, the cdf of a Chi-squared random variable has a closed form in terms of the incomplete Gamma function ... which, while that is a special function ... is nothing particularly 'special', and quite standard, and built into most software packages. By the same argument, something as basic as the CDF of a standard Normal cannot be expressed without an Error function.

Comment: @stollemn, if you know what this CDF looks like I am very interested.

Comment: Chi-square is a special case of gamma distribution, so the problem can be converted to sum of independent log-gamma random variables. Some references https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6364326, https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/11/23/4792,  https://www.casact.org/sites/default/files/2021-07/Log-Gamma-Distribution-Halliwell.pdf